# Setting a layout to use as empty view for a ListView in case adapter has zero items in a Activity

Tags: android

How to use a layout as empty view for a listview when the adapter has zero elements?

setEmptyView is not working with this code :

```
public class ZeroItemListActivity extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
    private ListView mMyListView;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mMyListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.MyListView);
        mMyListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems));
        LayoutInflater inflator=getLayoutInflater();
        View emptyView=inflator.inflate(R.layout.empty_list_item, null);
        //Empty view is set here
        mMyListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
    }
    public void addItem(View v){
        listItems.add("list Item");
        mMyListView.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Layouts used : empty_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Empty List,Click to add items"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello" />
    <ListView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/MyListView"></ListView>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/AddItemsButton"
        android:text="Add Items" android:onClick="addItem"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Btw mMyListView.invalidate(); is not the right call to refresh the list, you need to have something like ((ArrayAdapter) mMyListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 23):

The easiest way to get this done is to put the empty view in the main.xml layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/hello" />
        <ListView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/MyListView">
        </ListView>
      <!-- empty view -->  
      <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/emptyView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:text="Empty List,Click to add items">
            </Button>
       </LinearLayout>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/AddItemsButton"
        android:text="Add Items" 
        android:onClick="addItem"></Button>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Then, in your code, set your empty view like this:

```
mMyListView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptyView));
```

The reason your code isn't working is that the ListView and Empty view need to be in the same view heirarchy.  And your call to `inflate` pass null as the parent so they are in different heirarchies.

Comment: I believe that adding the `emptyView` to the same hierarchy of the `ListView` can also be done programmatically, by calling `((ViewGroup) mMyListView.getParent()).addView(emptyView)`.

Comment: but how can i place listener on click of button defined in Empty view

Answer (score 7):

The Android Dev tutorial for List Activity covers this topic:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Basically have your class extend ListActivity. Set your list id to `@id/android:list`and the "empty view" id to `@id/android:empty`in the same XML layout.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: can i use this with linearlayout and Activity class

Comment: This solution is good for ListActivity only, though good, but not applicable to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

When, inflating the view, you have to set the view parent to be part of the Layout hierarchy rather than pass null in some cases.

Replace

```
View emptyView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.empty_list_item, null);
```

with

```
View emptyView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.empty_list_item, (ViewGroup) mMyListView.getParent());
```

then you set the empty view as you did before with.

```
mMyListView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptyView));
```